# iPad icon shows as blank

Tags: ipad, xcode6, ios7.1

I have developed an iPhone/iPod-only app using Xcode 6 (minimum iOS version 7.1). I have added the necessary iPhone icon images in the .xcassets folder. I decided to test my app on my iPad 2 running 7.1. The app icon is showing as the default white iOS icon. I think I need to add icons for iPad somewhere in .xcassets but can't seem to find where. I tried googling for this, however, haven't been able to find an answer. A brief solution or a link to the answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you put them in .xcassets ? Did you put all the icon size ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to hard clean your project : Cmd + alt + Shift + K

Check you have all your icons in the Images.xcasset folder :

[image]

And then, be sure to select the right appIcon folder in your project target  :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here's the thing: I don't see the iPad app icon placeholder at all! Does it have anything to do with an iPhone/iPod-only app? I expected iOS to use icons from iPhone app icon placeholder when running my app on an iPad, but that doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: Nevermind, just restarted Xcode and the placeholders showed up! Thanks